# python + run sed command in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sed

I created python3 module file ( `sed_util_conf.py` ) that include `sed` Linux command that replaced **old** string with **new** for example - key - `http-server.https.port` and value )

```
def run_cli(action_details, command_to_run):
    print(action_details)
    print(command_to_run)
    errCode = os.system(command_to_run)
    if errCode != 0:
        print('failed, ' + command_to_run)
        sys.exit(-1)
    print(action_details + ' - action done')


def replace_line_do(File, OLD, NEW):
.
.
.

run_cli('run_sed_cli', f'sed -ie s/^{OLD}/{NEW}/  {File}')
```

on other python3 script I used the following python3 syntax in order to replace the "`OLD`" with new "`NEW`"

```
 sed_util_conf.replace_line_do(f'{file_path}', 'http-server.https.port=.*', f'http-server.https.port={val}')
```

example:

```
 sed_util_conf.replace_line_do(f'/etc/zomer_app/conf/config.zomer', 'http-server.https.port=.*', f'http-server.https.port={val}')
```

script is working and changed the OLD string with NEW string in file , but additionally we get another file that ended with "`e`"

for example

if we replaced the line on file - `/etc/zomer_app/conf/config.zomer`

then we get two files

```
/etc/zomer_app/conf/config.zomer
/etc/zomer_app/conf/config.zomere
```

the reason for that is the "`e`" charecter in syntx - `run_cli('sed', f'sed -ie s/^{OLD}/{NEW}/  {File}')`

from sed man page "`e`" means "`e script, --expression=script ,  add the script to the commands to be executed` "

**but I am not understand** how this "`e`" in `sed` create the additional file - `/etc/zomer_app/conf/config.zomere`  ?

Comment: Why are you using sed? Can't you just do this in python?

Comment: I will happy to get example , if you can

Comment: The reason you are getting an additional file with `e` is because after the `-i` flag for in place, you added `e` implying to sed to create a backup file with a similar name and an `e` to distinguish the backup and make the changes in place to the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `-ie` with `-i -e`.

You cannot stack options one after the other.

Comment: ok but still not make sense why we have additional file that ended with "e" , BTW as we seen some times file is empty

Comment: well it's up to sed to interpret your command line arguments - I would just fix the syntax and don't worry about how it handles edge cases in user input....

Comment: `-ie` should work with GNU sed.  Is this being run on a Mac?   The other option there might be to explicitly use `gsed`.   Based on other mac questions.

Comment: we run the python script on RHEL 7.9 version